# Can users on Okta be mapped to existing users in Sitecore 10.2?

Tags: federated-authentication, login

I'm using `Sitecore 10.2`, and adding `Okta` as a `federated` authentication method to login to the Sitecore CM.

I have added the Okta login implementation using [this link as a reference](https://www.xcentium.com/blog/2020/04/14/federated-auth-via-okta), and tested logging in and it's working. However it is creating a `brand new user`, with a `randomly generated name`, rather than mapping to the existing user with the same "email".

We already have some users on the Sitecore CM with specific roles and permissions set. I am wondering if it's possible to `map` the Okta users to `existing` old users on Sitecore if they are with the same email? Or do we have to reset the permissions for the newly generated users and use those instead?